# How to execute global npm modules via command line

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line-interface

I'm made a package that is meant to be installed globally and run via the command line.  `n` is an example of a package that does this, though it isn't an actual nodejs script, but a bash script.  I was considering aliases but that limits my support to the os's whose various aliasing methods I implement.  Is there a better, more universal way to do that that I am missing, or am I forced to insert alias-generating functions for each supported system?